# Getting certain data in excel

Tags: excel

I'm currently trying to develop an excel workbook for the purposes of automation. I'm relatively new to using Excel so my knowledge of more advanced techniques is somewhat limited. I understand the logic behind what I'm trying to do but I can't figure out what formulas to use to make it happen.

My current scenario is this, let's say I have Worksheet_1 and Worksheet_2. In Worksheet_1 I have the columns for Account_Number, Date, and Quantity. In Worksheet_2 I have similar columns except this one is a master tab where all data for all accounts across all dates is.

I am trying to pull the the quantity data from Worksheet_2 using the Account_Number and Date from Worksheet_1. The catch is that I need to pull the quantity for a particular Account_Number where the date in Worksheet_2 is the minimum date for that Account_Number that is also greater than or equal to the Date in Worksheet_1.

For example, let's say I have the following:

Worksheet_1

```
Account: Date: Quantity:    
578---01/01/2010----------
```

Worksheet_2

```
Account: Date: Quantity:    
578---02/31/2009--56    
578---02/02/2010--58    
578---02/03/2010--39    
602---02/02/2010--72
```

In this scenario I would want to pull the 58 number into the quantity column for Worksheet_1.

The logic works out to be :

Pull the minimum date within Worksheet_2 for a particular account that is at least equal to or greater than the Date in Worksheet_1

Assess minimum date row in Worksheet_2

Pull quantity from row from Worksheet_2 in Worksheet_1

Comment: Is Worksheet_2 always sorted by date?

Comment: Worksheet_2 is always sorted first by Account_Number and then by Date

Comment: BTW: February has only 28 days in 2009 not 31.  Just my OCD

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
=INDEX(Worksheet_2!C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Worksheet_2!$A$2:$A$100)/((Worksheet_2!$A$2:$A$100 = A2)*(Worksheet_2!$B$2:$B$100 >= B2)),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.